# A question on K(n) local spectra

Tags: homotopy-theory

Let $E$ be Morava E-theory at height $h$ and prime $p$. Is every $H_{\infty}$-ring spectrum over $E$ whose homotopy ring is isomorphic to a $W(F_{p^k})[[v_1, \dots, v_{n-1}]][\beta^{\pm 1}]$ a $K(h)$-local spectrum? Here $k$ is a positive integer and $\beta$ has degree 2.

Comment: Are $n$ and $h$ deliberately independent in this question?

Comment: Well you need h=n otherwise E itself would be a counterexample. But at height n: An even periodic, complex-oriented ring is K(n)-local iff its fgl has height \le n and it’s coefficients are complete wrt (p,v_1,...,v_{n-1}) (shifted down to degree zero).

Comment: E isn't a counterexample at h != n.

Comment: @PaulVankoughnett ah sorry! I thought E was height n and the other thing wanted to be height h.

Comment: @DylanWilson I am somewhat new to this stuff, could you explain in more detail reasoning for $h=n$? An easy to follow reference for K(n)-local ring spectra would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't exactly an answer but it's longer than a comment. Say $E$ is associated to the height $h$ formal group $\Gamma$ over $k$. Then $$\pi_0L_{K(h-1)}E = Wk((u_{h-1}))^\wedge_p[[u_1, \dotsc, u_{h-2}]].$$
This carries a height $h-1$ formal group, and maps into the Lubin-Tate ring
$$W(k((u_{h-1}))^{perf})[[u_1, \dotsc, u_{h-2}]]$$
of the base change of the universal deformation of $\Gamma$ over $k((u_{h-1}))^{perf}$. If there's a map of fields $k((u_{h-1}))^{perf} \to k$, then you can further map to the height $h-1$ Lubin-Tate ring, $$Wk[[u_1, \dotsc, u_{h-2}]].$$ For example, $k$ could be the perfect closure of $$\mathrm{colim}_n\,\mathbb{F}_q((x_1))((x_2))\dotsm ((x_n)).$$
Then, I think, you can use Goerss-Hopkins obstruction theory to realize this by a map from $E$ to a height $h-1$ $E$-theory, which is in particular $K(h-1)$-local.

It goes without saying that you can't do this over a finite field. If you want to reduce the height of the formal group, you need to make one of the power series generators invertible, and it doesn't seem like there's a lot of space to do that in the rings you mentioned, especially not in an $H_\infty$ way. But I can't think of how to prove anything.

Comment: Paul, when you write $k(\!(u_{h-1})\!)^\mathrm{perf}$, you mean the direct limit perfection, right? There's also a map from $W(k(\!(u_{h-1})\!)^\mathrm{perf})[\![u_1, \cdots, u_{h-2}]\!]$ (now using the inverse limit perfection) to $\pi_0 L_{K(h-1)} E$. I'd imagine the direct limit perfection is a more natural thing to consider, though, because you get a p-divisible group over it. Is there a ''coordinate-free'' construction of the p-div gp over $W(k(\!(u_{h-1})\!)^\mathrm{perf})[\![u_1, \cdots, u_{h-2}]\!]$ (direct limit perfection now...), i.e., which doesn't rely on the choice of the $u_i$?

Comment: @skd Yes, I mean the direct limit perfection. As for the p-divisible group: The formal part, at least, is the universal deformation of its base change to the residue field. This in turn is the base change of the universal deformation of the original height h formal group along $Wk[[u_1, ..., u_{h-1}]] \to k((u_{h-1}))^{perf}$, which doesn't rely on the choice of $u_i$ because $u_{h-1}$ is well-defined mod the lower $u_i$. I'm less sure about how to describe the whole height h p-divisible group.

Comment: I thought about constructing this p-divisible group a month ago, and I wrote some notes here: https://sanathdevalapurkar.github.io/chromotopy/2019/03/08/e-thy.html. If G_0 is the p-divisible group associated to the formal group Γ over k, and G is the universal deformation, then the induced p-divisible group H_0 over the direct limit perfection F = k((u_{h-1}))^perf has formal component of height h-1. You get an E_oo-ring map E(k, G_0) -> E(F, H_0), where E(k, G_0) is the Morava E-theory associated to the pair (k, G_0) (and similarly for E(F, H_0)). Since F is perfect...

Comment: ... the connected-etale sequence for H_0 splits, and so if H_0' denotes the connected component of the identity of H_0, then there is a map E(F, H_0) -> E(F, H_0'), which comes because the etale component of H_0 has trivial deformation theory. The target E(F, H_0') is a the Morava E-theory with pi_0 given by W(k((u_{h-1}))^perf)[[u_1, ..., u_{h-2}]] that you wrote about in your answer. Composing these two maps gives an E_oo-ring map E(k, G_0) -> E(F, H_0').